# Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) of power consumption signals

Tags: signal, fourier, fft

I want to compare two power consumption signals, i.e., how the power consumption varies throughout a day. Now I have two options:

- Take two raw power signals and compute the Euclidean distance between them
- Convert the input power signals using Fast Fourier Transform and then take Eucliden distance  of outputted FFT signals

I was ok with  the first option, but recently I remember that I read about second option somewhere. So, my question is - which option is better? and what is the intuition behind taking the FFT of input power time curves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take two raw signals and subtract, you will get a value that could be used to indicate the difference between the signals.

However, if you do the FFT you will lots of signal information, perhaps the power line is very noisy on one signal line. This would affect power consumption but may not be the component you wish to measure.

You could do multiple plots, say at 50Hz, 40Hz, etc. and compare.

**FFT gives more signal detail than Euclidean distance.**